# SPoint 2010 SPD woprkflow, day calculating problem

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow-variable

I've made a Workflow (by SPD 2010) where I calculate differences between 2 days. When I run this workflow once for 1 Doc.Library item, it calculate it right. BUT when I use Sheduled running WF to all items in library, this calculating get only 0.

In calcultating I use :  Find days between CI:column and variable:Today (output to variable:days)

I use at shedule HarePoint Workflow Scheduler program
Target is Document library

Single run WF result days = 1334,04
Sheduled running for all items in Library Days = 0

-timo

Answer (score 1):

SPD workflows Maximum Supported Single item, not at multiple items as my experience. At that time i used Event Receiver (when ever items added) workflow association to start multiple items.

Second Option Check with Pause action for specific time between each item.